# Vungle SDK Malicious Behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, vungle-ads

I have been received a mail from google, saying that your "We found your app is using a non-compliant version of Vungle SDK".
I search-out about this problem but i can't find-out the solution.
Any-one please help me out to this issue i will be very thank full to you.
I also attached the image of mail.[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're using an old version of the Vungle SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Our sincerest apologies for the flagging from Google.  We understand the pain it can be to update SDKs on short notice. The good news is that all recent Vungle SDKs starting, with Vungle’s SDK 6.5.3, are compliant.  More detail below:

The warning message relates to Android sideloading functionality present in only our 6.0-6.4 SDKs and has since been deprecated by Vungle. If you still have a pre-6.5 Android SDK present in your applications please update to the latest version. We learned this includes all tracks (production, beta, QA, etc.) which need to be updated. Please find the latest SDK [here](https://publisher.vungle.com/sdk/sdks/android) and Vungle's FAQ [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kw7DBOeTLHAlD_NTiNg0PR8DL7sZEbizIRcydSuDg44/edit).

Please always feel free to reach out to our support team for help at tech-support@vungle.com